# Create a Blank File If Not Already Exist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I added a blank file to the application resources but it is not found in the build, how would i programmatically check and create a file if it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can write only to application Documents directory.

```
- (BOOL)createFileAtPath:(NSString *)path contents:(NSData *)contents attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

NSFileManager doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I'm doing this but not working for empty file..              NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
  
  if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]){
   [fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
  }
  [fileManager release];

Comment: You must put something in it. Put an unique key or something. And test for that bool that the createFileAtPath returns. And when you access the file see if it has that key and the delete the key from it and write other data in it.

Comment: i succeeded with the same code, the problem was i wasn't specifying the documents path. Thank You.

Comment: @Syed - You can used `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` rather than create an instance.  @Alex - It is perfectly acceptable to send `nil` data and create an empty file. Much like Unix touch command does (see @Krumelur comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a custom build step (which is in fact a simple shell script). For example, just add `touch yourfilename`

Comment: Right click on the target in Xcode, choose Add>New build phase>New run script build phase. In the dialog that appears, just enter the shell commands you want to run.

Comment: will it create the file in the documents directory? @Krumelur

Comment: No, in the app bundle.